# How to Pull all docker container images from docker repo at once?

Tags: docker, containers

I have a private docker repo in which i have 10 container images stored. I want to pull all images to a machine. is there a way i can pull all images from a repo with a single command? some command like

```
docker pull  xx.xx.com/reponame/*
```

while researching I found ways to pull all tags of a single image; but no luck so far on all images

Answer (score 17):

Try this (it will update images that does not have running containers directly attached to them)

```
docker images | awk '(NR>1) && ($2!~/none/) {print $1":"$2}' | xargs -L1 docker pull
```

Try out this line out first to see what images will be covered:

```
docker images | awk '(NR>1) && ($2!~/none/) {print $1":"$2}'
```

Comment: maybe add a prune at the end: `docker image ls | awk '(NR>1) && ($2!~/none/) {print $1":"$2}' | xargs -L1 docker image pull; docker image prune -f`

Answer (score 9):

Could 'hack' this with `docker-compose`.

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.1'
services:
  a:
    image: a-image
  b:
    image: b-image
  c:
    image: c-image
# .....
```

`docker-compose pull --parallel`

Comment: Thank you for this! I was looking to do something different than what the question was. I came across your answer which worked for what I needed. Thanks for this hack.

Comment: This was exactly what I was after, thanks

Answer (score 6):

Use the format tag to filter the repository list. Although this will only pull the ones already existing in your host.

```
for image in $(docker images --format "{{.Repository}}"); do docker pull $image; done
```

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the docker documentation of the command: [docker pull](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/), you could use the option

```
--all-tags
```

to download all tagged images in the repository.

In your case, it would be :

```
docker pull --all-tags  xx.xx.com/reponame
```

Comment: This command is not working in my case? is it working for you?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what type of command is a single command, one-liner?

```
for repo in repo1 repo2 repo3; do docker pull xx.xx.com/$repo; done
```

Answer (score 2):

Run below shell script to pull ALL DOCKER IMAGES with ALL TAGS from a Docker Registry at once,

SHELL SCRIPT:

```
#/bin/bash
set-x
registry="registry name/ip:port"
repos=`curl -u cloudfx:cFx2018Aug http://$registry/v2/_catalog?n=300 | jq '.repositories[]' | tr -d '"'`
for repo in $repos; do 
   docker pull --all-tags $registry/$repo;
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy.

Install **jq** to parse JSON, edit the REGISTRY variable and run this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

REGISTRY="http://registry:5000"

for repo in $(curl -s $REGISTRY/v2/_catalog | jq -r '.repositories[]') ; do
    for tag in $(curl -s $REGISTRY/v2/$repo/tags/list | jq -r '.tags[]') ; do
        docker pull $REGISTRY/$repo:$tag
    done
done
```

For details on the Docker Registry API:
https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/docs/spec/api.md

Comment: This will use a lot of bandwidth and space to fetch all of those images. It's a shame there seems to be no way to add a repository that's searched on demand when an image is requested. You might get away with putting a full repo path in the Dockerfile rather than pre-fetching all of them to have as dependencies but I've not tested this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement - I needed to pull a specific set of tags from our ACR and found serially pulling using "docker pull" to be network inefficient.  So I took @johnharris85 answer and wrote a script taking my version tag

```
#!/bin/bash

export VERSION_TAG=${1:-latest}

cat <<EOF | docker compose -f - pull 
version: '3.7'
services:
  a:
    image: a-image:${VERSION_TAG}
  b:
    image: b-image:${VERSION_TAG}
  c:
    image: c-image:${VERSION_TAG}
```