# How to push muliple images to azure registry

Tags: azure, docker

I have a multiple container app that I want to deploy on azure, to create the images I'm using a docker compose file similar to this one:

```
version: '3.3'

services:

  app1:
    image: app1
    container_name: "app1"
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./app1
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

  app2:
    image: app2
    container_name: "app2"
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./app2
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Which helps me to automate the process, the issue is than every other step after this requires 
to use comands for each images indivdualy, in the pipeline I have this steps are:

1) Tag the image:

```
sudo docker tag app1 services.azurecr.io/samples/app1
```

2) Push the image to the azure registry:

```
sudo docker push services.azurecr.io/samples/app1
```

3) Deploy the container:

```
az container create \
    --name XXX
    --ports  5000 5100 \
    --memory 3 \
    --cpu 1 \
    --azure-file-volume-share-name legaldocuments \
    --azure-file-volume-mount-path /app/data \
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

Is there a way to include this in a single file for several containers? at least the part of tag and push the image.

Comment: You could create a bash script?

Comment: @mmking Yeah, I could but is not a clean solution I think, that's the last option

Comment: You can specify the `image:` to be the repository-qualified image name you want, and Compose will tag it for you.  That will save you one step, but it's not a complete answer here.

Answer (score 1):

To Push Multiple images to Azure Container Registry, they need to be tagged with the loginServer name of the Registry.

Follow the steps

**Step 1 : You need to attach a tag to those images,**

```
docker tag azurecontainerservicepoc acrarampoc/azurecontainerservicepoc:dev
```

**Step 2: Push Docker Images to Azure Container Registry**

```
docker push your_acr_name.azurecr.io/elasticsearch:6.2.4
```

Then inorder to push multiple images, you can try something with Bash script as,

In your case, it would be :

```
docker push --all-tags   your_acr_name.azurecr.io
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean, does the --all-tags parameter exists in docker? Or I have to create a bash script? if so, why is it called as docker ...<code> and not bash ...<code>

Comment: i do not know if there is a command , i asked you try from the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44339700/how-to-pull-all-docker-container-images-from-docker-repo-at-once

Comment: It seems that opton is only available to pull the images, not to push them i

Comment: hmm ok then, i am not sure

Comment: why is this upvoted, if this is clearly not the answer?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the docker tasks to achieve that (kinda), same is possible in the gui

```
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Push image
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: |
      $(dockerHub)
    repository: $(imageName)
    command: push
    tags: |
      test1
      test2
      etc
```

I dont think the equivalent works for building, so you'd have to have either a script with loop or multiple build steps to build